# How to add in lagged variables from two days ago to each row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have data of the following form

```
# create sample data
data = {'store name': ['Store A', 'Store A', 'Store B', 'Store B', 'Store C', 'Store C'],
        'time': ['2023-04-25 00:00:00', '2023-04-25 01:00:00', '2023-04-25 00:00:00', '2023-04-25 01:00:00', '2023-04-25 00:00:00', '2023-04-25 01:00:00'],
        'sales': [100, 200, 150, 250, 300, 350]}

# create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How can I add all data from two days ago for sales in each row?

```
         sales_0:            sales_1:             sales_2

Store A 2023-04-25 00:00:00  2023-04-23 23:00:00  2023-04-23 22:00:00
```

Usually to create time lags we use shift. However in this case that would not work.

Comment: In your sample data all dates are `2023-04-25`